# accessing session data in rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i need to check whether a Thing's id is in my session variable.

my instinct is to add a method to the Thing model which checks to see whether the Thing's id is in an array stored in the session variable.

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def pinned?
    session[:pinned].include? self.id
  end

end
```

The functionality I am trying to create is the user selects a bunch of different things for a list, which are then stored in a per-user session and then retrieved at a later date for printing.

Rails seems to prevent session access in the model without some hackery, which I'm keen to avoid. Maybe i'm approaching the problem the wrong way round, or the pinned? function belongs somewhere else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe pass it to the method as an argument instead of accessing it directly?

```
def pinned?(things)
    things.include? self.id
end

thing.pinned?(session[:pinned])
```